# How to fix 'A second operation started on this context' error on SignInManager.PasswordSignIn()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an MVC system that uses .net Identity login, however, when two separate users log into the system at roughly the same time, the user who clicks the button last gets an error saying;

> One or more errors occurred. A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

This error happens on the `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` line but I am stuck as to what I've done wrong.

Admittedly, I am not too familiar with OWIN, but if anyone has any clues as to what I can do to stop this happening that would be much appreciated.

To cover off a few things, I have already tried calling `PasswordSignIn` instead of `PasswordSingInAsync` and I've tried awaiting the call but its the same story - I believe this is because it's two entirely separate requests.

In brief, my code is set up as follows;

LoginController.cs

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    _identityManagement.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.PersistentLogin, false);

    //We do some stuff here but it fails before this point so code removed.
    return null;
}
```

IdentityManagement.cs

```
public class IdentityManagement
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationSignInManager.cs

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<SystemUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    DatabaseContext dbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<DatabaseContext>();

    app.CreatePerOwinContext<IUserStore<DatabaseContext>>(() => ApplicationUserStore.Create(dbContext));

    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
container.Register<DatabaseContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Verify();
```

Many Thanks,
Tom

As requested here is the stack trace

```
System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=One or more errors occurred.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
 at Controllers.LoginController.Login(LoginModel model) in C:\...\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 205
 at Controllers.LoginController.Index(LoginModel model) in C:\...\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 111
 at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
 at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2()

Inner Exception 1:
NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

Comment: Post the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. That contains any inner exceptions and the full call stack which shows the calls that led to that exception. The exception may not have occurred in the posted methods at all. The only line in the question's code that actually does anything is PasswordSigniInAsync. The rest is just configuration.

Comment: That error is from the inner exception, I've edited the post to include the stack trace.

Comment: That call stack shows that *Index()* called `Login()` directly instead of letting the framework call it when necessary, eg in response to a POST from a form. It also shows that a call to `.Result` was made instead of using `await`. Post the code for `Index` and `Login`, especially the code in lines 111 and 205. If `Index()` calls an asynchronous method it should use `async` itself and await that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a second user ( which is running in different thread ) is trying to access the DatabaseContext while it is used by first user. You should create a new DatabaseContext for every thread

Comment: Hi Ikacho - I think you are on the right lines here but would you be able to explain what is wrong in my setup or what I would need to change to accomplish this? Many Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 2):

The error explains what's wrong and how to fix it - an `await` is missing from an asynchronous operation. The only such operation is in the first snippet :

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    _identityManagement.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.PersistentLogin, false);

    //We do some stuff here but it fails before this point so code removed.
    return null;
}
```

By convention asynchronous methods end in `Async` and yet, nothing awaits for `PasswordSignInAsync` to complete before continuing and returning. [PasswordSignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is indeed an asynchronous method.

This means that the user hasn't logged in by the time this method returns. For all anyone knows login may have failed.

Any subsequent attempts to login can easily happen *before* the first attempt finishes. It also means that the sign-in cookie is never set and any subsequent calls to the site will try to login again.

Change the method to :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    var result=await _identityManagement.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.PersistentLogin, false);
    if(result.Succeeded)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Panagiotis, I've tried this but It hasn't solved the problem, unfortunately. I think the await/second operation is a bit of a red herring since this is two separate users on two different threads trying to login. Many Thanks, Tom

Comment: @TomKirkland you haven't posted the full exception, only the message so people have to guess. The only line in the question's code that actually does anything is `PasswordSigniInAsync`. The rest is just configuration. Post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. That contains any inner exceptions and the full call stack which shows the calls that led to that exception. The exception may not have occured in the posted methods at all

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both, it put me onto the right track and I've now solved the issue.

In **Startup.auth.cs** I had the following code

```
DatabaseContext dbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<DatabaseContext>();
app.CreatePerOwinContext<IUserStore<SystemUser>>(() => ApplicationUserStore.Create(dbContext));
```

I've now changed it to the following which works for multiple simultaneous login requests

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<IUserStore<SystemUser>>(() => ApplicationUserStore.Create(new DatabaseContext()));
```

Presumably, the was I was declaring the dbContext here was using the same one for every instance of "SystemUser"

Thank you both again for the help and ideas.

Tom